# Trying to pull data from parse and render with underscore.js getting empty frields

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, parse-platform

Trying to pull data from parse.com and use underscore.js I tried using this to build a table of the data. When I run it with hard coded json it works but when I try running it with pulled data returns an empty table.

```
          Parse.initialize("", "");


        var allDeals = Parse.Object.extend("Deal");
        var query = new Parse.Query(allDeals);


        query.find({
            success: function(results){


                var deals = JSON.stringify(results); 

             var template = $("#usageList").html();
             $("#target").html(_.template(template,{deals:deals}));




            },
            error: function(error) {
                alert('something was wrong');
            }
        });
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @mu said it would be easier to see whats in results..
But I have run into this with Parse before. Taking a guess.. You can try this

```
$('#target').html(_.template(template, { deals: results.models }));
```

"results" is a backbone collection and "models" holds the array of objects you are after.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you're getting a JavaScript object of some sort in `results` in your `success` callback. Then you serialize that to a JSON string with:

```
var deals = JSON.stringify(results);
```

That leaves you with a string in `deals` and your template probably doesn't know what to do with a string, it probably wants an object or whatever was in `results` in the first place. Try skipping the stringification and just feed `results` straight into the template:

```
$('#target').html(_.template(template, { deals: results }));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, the code now shows the right amount of fields but doesn't show the data. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Well, what does `results` look like and what does the template look like?